# How to do multi-level seeding in by using Eloquent Relationships in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-seeding

Here is the table stucture

- Table A
- Table B has foreign key a_id
- Table C has foreign key a_id and b_id

I am trying to Seed these three tables with Eloquent Relationships

Here is my code structure

```php
class A extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function b()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(B::class);
    }

    public function c()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(C::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class B extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function c()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(C::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class C extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [...];
}
```

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\A::factory(5)
            ->has(\App\Models\B::factory(2))
            ->has(\App\Models\C::factory(1))
            ->create();
    }
}
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'b_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `c` (... `a_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Answer (score 0):

Your seeder will create 5 `A` models.

For each of these 5 `A`, it's going to try and do two things

- create 2 `B`, passing in `a_id`.
- create 1 `C`, passing in `a_id`, but not passing any `b_id`.

---

Here's how each of those `A` models would look like.

```
// A model
{
    id: 1
    b: [
        // B model
        {
            id: 1,
            a_id: 1
        },
        // B model
        {
            id: 2,
            a_id: 1
        },
    ],
    c: [
        // C model
        {
            id: 1,
            a_id: 1,
        ->  b_id: null <- This will throw the error because b_id is not a nullable column
        },
    ],
}
```

---

To fix it you will need to either remove `has(\App\Models\C::class)` or make a `B` model to associate with it.

You need to define the `belongsTo` relationship for this to work.

```php
# B model
public function a()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(A::class);
}
```

```php
# C model
public function a()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(A::class);
}

public function b()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(B::class);
}
```

For example

```php
use App\Models\A;
use App\Models\B;
use App\Models\C;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $b = B::factory()->for(A::factory())->create();

        A::factory(5)
            ->has(B::factory(2))
            ->has(C::factory(1)->for($b))
            ->create();
    }
}
```

You could also not create everything in one statement.

```php
use App\Models\A;
use App\Models\B;
use App\Models\C;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $A_models = A::factory(5)
            ->has(B::factory(2))
            ->create();

        foreach ($A_models as $A) {
            $b_id = $A->b->pluck('id')->random();
            $c = C::factory()->make(['b_id' => $b_id]);

            $a->c()->save($c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I have Merchant, Shop and Campaign as A,B and C. When is try this

`
        $shop = Shop::factory()->for(Merchant::factory())->create();
        
        Merchant::factory(5)
            ->has(Shop::factory(2))
            ->has(Campaign::factory(1)->for($shop))
            ->create();
`
its shows 

  BadMethodCallException

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Shop::merchant()

Comment: You need to define the `belongsTo` relationship for it to work. `public function merchant() { return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class); }` in your `Shop` model.

Comment: Sweet! So it needs both belongsTo in Shop and hasMany in Merchant?

Comment: One relational issue thought,
_Merchant 1 has Shop 1_ - But in Campaign table one Campain of Shop 1 showing  Merchant 4 (who has a different shop) in merchant_id

Comment: You should edit your question with those model names and explain better those constraints.

Comment: I have provided the Model names and explained the constraints with two examples. I did not find what could be a valid reason to downvote my question. Thank you for your help, I will try something different.